# I just want to ask if there is any camera module (pi cam) that can do both nightvision and day recording?

Tags: raspicam

I'm planning to make a project with a raspberry pi and pi cam as a toy car surveillance.

IP cam is commonly used, so I was thinking if the pi cam has the same features with the IP cam such as the nightvision (auto detect or could be coded).

Please guide me. Thank you

Comment: Not an answer, but technically I believe the difference between the noir cam and the normal one is that the normal one has an infrared filter *removed* -- [a bit about that here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/12780/5538), which implies to me it is probably a one or the other way deal with that.  Also relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_and_night_camera  ...Which implies what the pi camera doesn't have that a day/night camera has is a specialized DSP.

Comment: Not the normal PI camera. Other yes, of course there are. However, I suggest to deeply look on the web: is full of ideas and component!! Have a look [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=night%20vision%20camera%20rasperry%20pi&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a Pi cam that can do both. It can be set on auto detect to record during the day and night. I found this one on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RJRBP65).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very much helpful for my project :)

Comment: You're very much welcome!